# MySQL Slow Log issues - long_query_time does not go into effect

Tags: mysql

I have followed a few tutorials in tracking down slow queries through the slow query log.

I have tried changing long_query_time to the value of 1 for testing purposes, but whatever I do, a query only makes it into the log when the default time of 10 is reached.

I tried:

```
set @@GLOBAL.long_query_time = 1;
set global long_query_time = 1;
```

When using either of these commands:

```
show variables like '%long%';
show global variables like '%long%';
```

I get the result that the variable was changed.

I have the exact same query running, just adding more `LEFT JOIN` entries to make it run longer. Whenever the query runs 10 seconds or longer, it is logged, but it does NOT show up in the log when it runs less than that, even though all my variables appear to say they are changed.

I am logged into MySQL as root as I make these changes.

I restarted Apache and MySQL, still no dice.

My version information is:

Server version: 5.1.63-log SUSE MySQL RPM

When I query both the session and the global variables (I tried both), I get this:

```
mysql> show variables like '%long%';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| long_query_time    | 1.000000 |
| max_long_data_size | 1048576  |
+--------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like '%long%';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| long_query_time    | 1.000000 |
| max_long_data_size | 1048576  |
+--------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The general logging feature is obviously on, and it is redirected to `TABLE` or I wouldn't get an entry in the log at all.

The setting `log_queries_not_using_indexes` if turned on starts logging EVERY query even if it does not take 1 second to execute.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are those _new_ connections that still not log, or were they already connected? As far as I know, its set when connecting, [see also this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38704).

Comment: Oh, and fwiw: when testing this, a `SELECT SLEEP(2);` is less resource intensive then just joining all kinds of things ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `sleep`, I'll try that next time :-) Otherwise, not quite sure what defines a "new connection" - in this case, I am running both an SQL GUI (NaviCat) which keeps me connected to the database, but then I run the test query multiple times by hand. However, in NaviCat, I'm connected to a different database user - when I set the variables, I am connected via terminal as root. But I set the `long_query_time` variable both as session and global variables with the same results. I hope this helps...

Comment: OK, do this: (1) set the global timeout (2) just exit from whatever connection you are using: totally close that gui application (3) restart it, and see what happens with that _new_ connection.

Comment: Duh, I guess I am thinking way too complicated :-) This worked! Please write this as an answer so I can accept it :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The configuration below turns MySQL to log queries which execution time is more than half second:

```
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 0.5
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0
```